# Mercurial: Concrete examples of issues using hg pull --rebase

Tags: mercurial, rebase

I'm struggling to find the mercurial workflow that fits the way that we work.

I'm currently favouring a clone per feature but that is quite a change in mindset moving from Subversion. We'll also have issues with the current expense we have in setting up environments.

Using hg pull --rebase seems to give us more of a Subversion-like workflow but from reading around I'm wary of using it.

I think I understand the concepts and I can see that rewriting the history is not ideal but I can't seem to come up with any scenarios which I personally would consider unacceptable.

I'd like to know what are the 'worst' scenarios that hg pull --rebase could create either theoretical or from experience. I'd like concrete examples rather than views on whether you 'should' rewrite history. Not that I'm against people having opinions, just that there already seem to be a lot of them expressed on the internet without many examples to back them up ;)

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve ? It's pretty difficult to understand that question without knowing why simply branching and merging is not acceptable.

Comment: The problem I have is with certain developers wanting to work with multiple patches in one repository. I'm aware of the alternatives, branching, shelving, MQ etc but none is an easy fit. I really want to know what the cons of rebasing are short of losing history which in the case of small patches is likely unimportant. I suspect I don't fully understand the impact of rebasing and could do with examples of where it is a bad thing.

Comment: Ignore that I'm confusing myself. I'd got it into my head that I could hg pull --rebase into a repository with uncommitted changes which you can't.

Comment: Hi. What problems are caused by your developers wanting to work with multiple patches in a single repository? Are the issues when they push back their changes? How were you previously working with Subversion?

Comment: So you want your developers want to push their *complete* changes while leaving ongoing work as *uncommitted* changes?

Comment: Yep thats right. I was thinking that hg pull --rebase would allow them to do that.

Comment: Two of the biggest features in DVCS are being able to commit locally and competent branching and merging. Leaving ongoing work uncommitted and rebasing changes makes it no better than Subversion. I know the transition to Mercurial can be confusing, but if you don't embrace its workflow, you'll end up making it much harder on yourself in the long run.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first thing new Mercurial converts need to learn is to get comfortable committing incomplete code. Subversion taught us that you shouldn't commit broken code. Now it's time to unlearn that habit. Committing frequently gives you a lot more flexibility in your workflow.

The main problem I see with `hg pull --rebase` is the ability to break a merge without any way to undo. The DVCS model is based on the idea of tracking history explicitly, and rebasing subverts that idea by saying that all of my changes came after all of your changes, even though we were really working on them at the same time. And because I don't know what your changes are (because I was basing my code off of earlier changesets) it's harder for me to know that my code, on top of yours, won't break something. You also lose the branching capabilities by rebasing, which is really the whole idea behind DVCSs.

Our workflow (which we've built an [entire Mercurial hosting system](http://kilnhg.com/) around) is based on keeping multiple clones, or branch repositories, as we call them. Each dev or small team has their own branch repository, which is just a clone of the "central" repository. All of my new features and large bug fixes go into my personal branch repo. I can get that code peer reviewed, and once it's deemed ready, I can merge it into the central repo.

This gives me a few nice benefits. First, I won't be breaking the build, as all of my changes are in their own repo until they're "ready". Second, I can make another branch repo if I need to do a separate feature, or if I have something longer-running, like for the next major version. And third, I can easily get a change into the central repo if there's a bug that needs to be fixed quickly.

That said, there are a couple different ways you can use this workflow. The most simple, and the one I started with, is just keeping separate clones. So I'll have `website-central`, `website-tghw`, etc. It works well, especially since you can push and pull between them locally. More recently, I've started keeping multiple heads in the same repo, using the [remotebranches](http://bitbucket.org/tghw/hg-remotebranches) extension to help manage them and [hg nudge](http://hgtip.com/tips/advanced/2009-09-28-nudge-a-gentler-push/) to keep from pushing everything at once.

Of course, some people don't like this workflow as much, usually because their Mercurial server makes it hard to make server-side clones. In that case, you can also look at using [named branches](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/NamedBranches) to help keep your features straight. Unfortunately, they're not quite as flexible as Git branches (which is why we prefer branch repos) but they work well once you understand how to close branches, and why you can't really get rid of them once you start one.

This is getting a bit long, so I'll wrap it up by encouraging you to embrace the superior branching and merging that Mercurial provides (over SVN). There is definitely a learning curve, but once you get the hang of it, it really does make things easier.

Comment: Thanks. I'm fine with committing broken code if I can then selectively push complete code without pushing the broken code. This means either branching or a clone per feature. Branching seems to me to add a layer of complexity we don't want and clone per feature give us problems at the minute because of the size of our codebase / cost of setting up environments.

Comment: That's why I've moved more and more towards keeping all of the branches in my local repo, and just jumping between heads. I don't have to set up the whole environment again, and I only have to recompile the files that are different between the heads. Check out remotebranches.

Comment: Sounds like I need to play around with branches a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

From the question comments, your root issue is that you have developers working on several features/bug fixes/issues at one time and having uncommitted work in their working directory along with some completed work that is ready to be pushed back to the central repository.

There's a really nice exchange that covers the issue well and leads on to a number of ways forward.

http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.mercurial.general/19704

There are ways you can get around keeping your uncommitted changes, e.g. by having [a separate clone to handle merges](http://blogs.oracle.com/tor/entry/mercurial_tip_checking_in_regularly), but my advice would be to embrace the distributed way of working and commit as often as you like - if you really feel the need you can combine the last few local commits into a single changeset (using MQ, for example) before pushing.

Comment: Thanks Nick. Useful link. Found the comments by Giorgos Keramidas very informative.