# Why does Mercurial make you pull/update/merge for unrelated files?

Tags: mercurial

For larger teams, having to pull/update/merge then commit each time makes no sense to me, specifically when the files that were changed by other developers have nothing to do with my changeset files.

i.e. I change file1.txt, and someone else changes file10.txt.  Why must I merge on my computer before being allowed to push?

It **makes pushing a big pain**, as you have to constantly pull/update/merge if many developers are commiting.

**Also, it makes your changeset look much larger than it was since it shows your merges as seperate commits.**

Comment: Mercurial can't know which files are unrelated. How often are you pushing to your central repo?

Comment: if there are 50-100 developers, it is a big pain.

Comment: Are 50-100 developers really working on the same code base, or are they actually working on different sub-projects which are in the same repository? I've been at companies that tried to use mercurial having come from other VCSs, and just lumped all the code in one big repo. They cursed the merges, but really the problem was that they should have had lots of small repos which were independent of each other and brought them together in a project using sub-repos.

Comment: Also, are people pushing after each commit? Often that is not necessary, you should only push when you have something that you want to share immediately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mercurial makes you do this since its atomic unit isn't a file but a changeset. That is a node containing a group of changes. Each changeset is an individual node in history and represents what that person did. This does result in you having to merge even if no common files where changes (which would be a simple automatic merge). These merge nodes are important since they are part of your repositories history and gives Mercurial more information for future merges with ancestral information.

That said there is an extension you can use that would clean up your history a bit (but won't resolve your issue with needing to pull before you push). It is called the [rebase extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension), it is shipped with Mercurial but disabled by default. It adds a new arumument to [pull](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension#Integration_with_pull) that looks like:

```
hg pull --rebase
```

This will pull new changes and moves your local changeset linearly above them without having a merge changset. However, I would urge against using this since you do lose information about your repository since you are re-writing its history. Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3760022/50660) for information about some issues that this may cause.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you could try using [rebase](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension), which will avoid the merge commits, but it is not without its own perils. You can also collapse to one step by doing "hg pull --update", rather than separate hg pull; hg update commands.

As for why you must merge on your computer: this is a direct consequence of mercurial being a distributed version control system. There is no central server which can be considered canonical (unless you create one by convention), so there is no other "place" where the merge could occur. You are the only one who can decide how the information in your repo should be combined with the information in the remote repo. The results of these decisions must be recorded, and that is the origin of the merge commit.

Also, in your example the merge would happen without user interaction since there are no conflicts (the same would be true with rebase), so I don't see why that is a problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Because having changes in disjunct files does not guarantee that they are independent.**

When you pull in changes, even if they are in files that are untouched by your local changes, it can cause your local changes to stop working. E.g. an interface that you access from newly written code could have been changed.

This is why there is always a merge step inbetween, so that a human can review the changes, test for issues, and address them before integrating the changes back into the main repository. This step is very important, because skipping it risks blocking all those 50-100 colleagues (which is very expensive).

I would take Lasse’s advice and push less often. Merging isn’t a big deal if you only need to do it twice or thrice a day. Also maybe create smaller team repositories (or branches) that are merged with the main repository daily by a designated person.